# Confusion on caveats of using lastValueFrom

Tags: angular, rxjs

RXjs lastValueFrom documentation states:

WARNING: Only use this with observables you know will complete. If the source observable does not complete, you will end up with a promise that is hung up, and potentially all of the state of an async function hanging out in memory.

Does this mean "know will EMIT complete", or "know will end at some point by either emitting complete or error?" This is causing confusion on our team because HTTPclient sometimes emits error instead of complete, and we can not determine from documentation if this will cause the promise to 'hang up and hang out in memory."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
lastValueFrom(interval(1000))
```

This will return a promise that will never resolve. This is what they're talking about. Errors won't be a problem.

So the answer to your question is "know will end at some point by either emitting complete or error"... except I don't know that it makes sense to say "emit complete". `EMPTY`, for example, is an observable that completes, but it doesn't *emit* anything.

Comment: Thank you!  That was my suspicion, but unfortunately I can't read their code well enough to prove it.  That leaves me with just the documentation to go by.  The documentation unfortunately uses the word "completed", which due its specific meaning is causes us confusion.

Comment: Good point. It should say "close", not "complete".

Answer (score 0):

In the docs:

Check out the line right before the warning:

> If the observable stream emits an error, the returned promise will reject with that error.

At this point you needn't worry about RxJS anymore, you can look into how promises work. A promise that has rejected or resolved is a promise that is decisively **not** hung up. A promise resolves or rejects exactly once and thereafter doesn't pollute the JavaScript event loop.

That being said, perhaps the warning in the RxJS docs is a bit poorly worded.

Answer (score -1):

An observable that throws an error doesn't complete.

So `lastValueFrom` will also emit an error.

For example :

```
function foo(): Promise<void> {
  return lastValueFrom(
    of().pipe(switchMap(() => throwError(() => new Error('test'))))
  );
}

async function bar(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    console.log(await foo()); // won't log
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // logs the error
  }
}

bar();
```

Comment: I know it will emit an error, but will the promise "get hung up and  and potentially all of the state of an async function be hanging out in memory" ?  It seems if it emits an error, and lastvaluefrom emits the error, there is no reason for it to get hung up.

Comment: @OhNoDaddyO, The warning means what it means. If your observable doesn't complete (a subject for example), `lastValueFrom` will never emit a value and await indefinitely .

Comment: But is an observable that emitted an error considered complete in this case?

Comment: @OhNoDaddyO No. It will throw an error. This error can't only be caught in a try/catch when awaiting.

Comment: Then why do people use lastValueFrom for http gets?  Wouldn't that mean if there was a network error then an error would be emitted, but the observation would never complete, therefor hanging up the state of the async function in memory?

Comment: @OhNoDaddyO Error is not a completion but will stop the observable and throw an Error which will stop the current task.

Comment: So you are saying it is stopped, but it is not completed, therefor state of the async function IS hung in memory?

Comment: @OhNoDaddyO Nothing is hung when an error is thrown, the whole task is interrupted up until the closest try/catch.

Comment: Does that mean the documentation is misleading when it says the observable must be completed to prevent this issue?  Would it be more correct to say it must be completed OR error?  Or does completed mean something different in this case?

Comment: @OhNoDaddyO The documentation is correct, `lastValueFrom` won't emit a value on error. A complete means the observable is now closed and will never emit something else.

Comment: Ok, so in this case, an observation that threw an error is considered complete because it is now closed and will never emit something else.  Even though the observation never emitted complete, it is completed?

Comment: Complete has a precise meaning: completed without error.

Comment: Then that means, according to the documentation, that if the httpget observable throws an error, it is not complete.  Since it is not complete, you end up with a promise that is hung up, and potentially all of the state of an async function hanging out in memory.